# SUM() function error using MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I want to get the quatity of every product for the period between the current month and 24 months ahead. My sql query returns sums for the next month only.

```
SELECT `products`, `date`, SUM(`quantity`)
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `date` 
BETWEEN CURDATE()
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 MONTH)
GROUP BY `products`
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the dateformat in the column date the same as the one shown by curdate()

Comment: Well, since `date` isn't in your `GROUP BY` nor in an aggregate function, most probably the first encountered (in whatever order MySQL chooses to traverse the table) is shown, not necessarily summed. This would be an error in strict sql. What do you _want_ de `date` column in your resultset to show?

Comment: Why did you just change the accepted answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with MONTHS not MONTH

```
    AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 MONTHS)
```

try this

```
SELECT `products`, `date`,quantity ,SUM(`quantity`)
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `date` 
BETWEEN CURDATE()
AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 MONTHS)
GROUP BY `products` , `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group on `date`, as currently MySQL is selecting a single (indeterminate) `date` from each group:

```sql
GROUP BY `products`, `date`
```